# Scalatra JSON guide code not compiling

Tags: scala, scalatra

I copied the instructions on the JSON formatting Guide found here: http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/formats/json.html

Below is MyScalatraServlet.scala file with all of the code I embedded to test out JSON formatting:

```
package net.example.testapp

import org.scalatra._
import scalate.ScalateSupport

// JSON-related libraries
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}

// JSON handling support from Scalatra
import org.scalatra.json._

class MyScalatraServlet extends TestAppStack with JacksonJsonSupport {

  get("/") {
    FlowerData.all
  }

}

// Sets up automatic case class to JSON output serialization, required by
// the JValueResult trait.
protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

case class Flower(slug: String, name: String)

object FlowerData {

  /**
   * Some fake flowers data so we can simulate retrievals.
   */
  var all = List(
      Flower("yellow-tulip", "Yellow Tulip"),
      Flower("red-rose", "Red Rose"),
      Flower("black-rose", "Black Rose"))
}
```

It seems the compiler does not like the following line:

```
protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats
```

Here's the error message:

```
[error] /Users/test/test-app/src/main/scala/net/example/testapp/MyScalatraServlet.scala:22: expected start of definition
[error] protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 17, 2013 4:04:34 PM
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `val jsonFormats` is just kinda floating there, not tied to a class or anything. A `val` needs to be defined as part of another construct like a trait, class or object. Try moving it inside of that servlet class, just before the call to `get("/")`

Comment: I agree- according the JSON guide, "putting [protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats] right underneath the controller class definition will allow your controller to automatically convert Scalatra action results to JSON".